# hover and hover out not working properly

Tags: jquery, hover

i am trying to make an effect that when i hover over a div, it moves up and shows another div beneath it. and when i hover out, it goes back into its position. but but what is happening is that when i keep my mousE ON  THAT DIV, it keeps on animating to and fro, which i dont want.

surprisingly, i use the same jquery code that i have used here in some other html and it worked fine. please tell a way where the div just goies off on hovering, and does not keep on animatring, and goes back on when i hover out. here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <style>
        body{ overflow:hidden; padding:0; margin:0;}
        .boxouter{ width:100%; float:left; }
        .box1{ background-color:#CC0000; height:100%; width:25%; height:800px; float:left; position:absolute;}
        .box2{ background-color:#339900; height:100%; width:25%; height:800px; margin-left:25%; float:left; position:absolute;}
        .box3{ background-color:#FFCC00; height:100%; width:25%; height:800px; margin-left:50%; float:left; position:absolute;}
        .box4{ background-color:#0000CC; height:100%; width:25%; height:800px; float:left; margin-left:75%; position:absolute;}
        .box1_hide{ background-color:#666; height:100%; width:25%; height:800px; float:left; position:absolute; z-index:-1;}
    </style>
    <script>   
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $(".box1").mouseenter(function(){
            $(".box1").stop().animate({height:"0px"},200);
        });

           $(".box1").mouseleave(function(){ 
            $(".box1").stop().animate({height:"800px"},200);
        });
        });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="boxouter">
   <div class="box1"></div><div class="box1_hide">click here</div>
   <div class="box2"></div>
   <div class="box3"></div>
   <div class="box4"></div></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that the box with the leave event is getting smaller and slides to the top. Everytime its border touches your mouse pointer the event is triggered again. The same when it's getting bigger.

**Solution 1**

Just use `box1_hide` for the mouseleave ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aZSAN/1/)):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box1").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".box1").stop().animate({height:"0px"},200);
    });

    $(".box1_hide").mouseleave(function(){ 
        $(".box1").stop().animate({height:"800px"},200);
    });
});
```

**Solution 2 (better)**

The only problem with solution 1 is, that when you move your mouse too fast `box1` doesn't hide again.
So you could use another solution. Wrap your overlay and the hidden div with another div and add your events to it ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aZSAN/6/)).

```
<div class="box-wrapper"><div class="box1"></div><div class="box1_hide">click here</div></div>
```

And jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box-wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".box1", this).stop().animate({height:"0px"},200);
    });

    $(".box-wrapper").mouseleave(function(){ 
        $(".box1", this).stop().animate({height:"800px"},200);
    });
});
```